# meteor helper function on @index in #each not working - index undefined

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to increment a value in an #each loop using a helper, but it seems like the @index variable in the loop is not being passed.

Here's what the loop looks like:

```
{{#each thing.subthing}}
    {{offset @index}}
{{/each}}
```

And here's the helper:

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
    "offset": function(index){
        index += 5;
        console.log("index = "+index);
        return index;
    }
});
```

The console is logging "undefined", even if I check the value of index before modifying it.

Any idea what's going wrong? I'm using meteor 1.2.1, so it's not an issue with @index not being available to me.

Comment: Are you sure that `thing.subthing` is iterable? Can you show an instance of it?

Comment: Yup - I can see the iterated contents fine. It's just the @index that's not working. In fact it's not working even without the helper (i.e. if I just use {{@index}} in the each loop).

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Log `thing.subthing` itself, try to iterate a plain array and see if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a versioning issue. My meteor install was at 1.2.1, but one of the components must have needed an update. I ran meteor --update and now everything is working fine :-)